# replacing characters in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, html-entities

I am trying to replace the `&` in "Sydney & Melbourne" with `&amp;`.
But it's not working.

I have tried a few different ways as follows:

- with for loop and if statement:

  ```
  for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
      if(str[i]==="&"){
        str[i]="&amp;";
      }
  ```
- with regex and replace:

  ```
  var myRegExp = /\b&\b/;

  str = str.replace(myRegExp,"&amp;");
  return str;
  ```

I do understand that `&` and `&amp;` are the same things and so the result probably comes out at as `&` (in fact it's happening as I am writing it here on stack overflow). But is there a way around it?

Comment: Remove `\b` from regex. `'Sydney & Melbourne'.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');`

Comment: tried that but it didn't work:(

Comment: Thanks! I stand corrected, it did work. just curious as to why single quotes worked but the double quotes didn't.

Comment: It is impossible that `replace(/&/g, '&amp;`)` would not work, whether with double quotes or single quotes.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks but unfortunately, I have been trying to solve this since morning and have been through every which hoop but nothing worked with double quotes. As soon as I changed all my double quotes to single quotes, boom!

Comment: @torazaburo may i also ask, why did I need to omit "/b", i thought to specify  spacing before and after a word or character, I needed to use /b.

Comment: Maybe your double quotes were accidentally some kind of "smart quotes", that were themselves breaking things.  That's why changing the quotes seemed to fix the problem. (just a thought.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Your first try

> with for loop and if statement:

```
for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    if(str[i]==="&"){
      str[i]="&amp;";
    }
}
```

Of course this won't work. JS strings are [**immutable**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type), which means

> Once a string is created, it is not possible to modify it

It won't cause a run-time error, but it won't do anything. (Even if JS strings were not immutable, which they are, you could not replace one character with multiple characters.)

#### Your second try

> with regex and replace:

```
var myRegExp = /\b&\b/;

str = str.replace(myRegExp,"&amp;");
return str;
```

Of course this won't work. There is no word boundary between a space and an ampersand. See the definition of [**word boundary**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary):

> A word boundary matches the position where a word character is not followed or preceded by another word-character.

where "word character" is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

#### But why?

However, the real question is why you want to do this. If you simply want to insert this string into the DOM as text, then do so using `textContent`:

```
document.getElementById("city").textContent = "Sydney & Melbourne";
```

(instead of using `innerHTML`). In jQuery, if you happen to be using that, use `text()` instead of `html()`. This approach has the advantage that it won't be confused by other HTML characters in the string, notably `<`.

If your issue is related to `&` in a URL, you shouldn't be HTML-escaping it--you should be URI-encoding it, but you probably already knew that.

If your issue is that you are passing this to a server which expects properly encoded HTML strings, then you should reconsider your API design. In general, it's better to store the raw strings on the server, and decode/encode/escape/unescape them when necessary--remember that server data might be displayed in contexts other than browser. If you absolutely do want to send the server properly HTML-escaped strings, then you need to worry about more than just `&`, but also the other special HTML characters. For this, you should use some utility that is probably available in your favorite library, or the standard:

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = str;
  return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, in order to replace the `&`, you would need to have the `&` surrounded by word characters (ex: `a&b`).

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://regex101.com/r/6YHSJ8/1) that explains visually what I mean about the regex you were trying to use.

Instead, just target the `&` directly:

```js
var string = 'Sydney & Melbourne';

string = string.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');

console.log(string);
```

Comment: Thank you both! @kevBot - The single quotes worked but the double quotes didn't work?? why is this?

Comment: @nishkaush, It works fine for me with double quotes. Are you referring to when you were trying to use the word boundaries (`\b`)?

Comment: Hi kevbot @kevbot - i initially started without /b but then i thought maybe "&" has spaces before and after, so i ought to add /b. Its so strange that this didn't work when everyone here is saying it should.

Comment: If you see @torazaburo's answer, he details a little more of "why" it didn't work. I figured I'd point you there since he wrote up the "why" before I did